# Manga where man is followed by spirits that are gods

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga a couple of months ago. In this manga we follow our main character who is in a fantasy world (I do not believe he has reincarnated or transferred, he was born in this world I think). In this manga the main character I believe is a summoner that summons spirits. What he does not realise is that he is follow by many spirits, but these are no ordinary spirits but are gods. In this world the god give adventurers blessings so they can use their skills.

In the manga the main character is not welcomed in this region, so he decides to leave but what he doesn't realize is that this dooms this region because the spirit/gods that follow him take their blessings away from the adventurers in that region because they did not accept him. This dooms them because they need to fight monsters to survive.

Comment: I swear I've read this but now I can't find it. Does he have two main spirit companions, both in the form of attractive women? Is there a scene where one of them is speaking to an assembly of all the spirits of the country and riling them up, encouraging them to leave (they do) for kicking the MC out? I'm aware this isn't helpful, but maybe it'll jog your memory for some other details if it is the same story. In particular, I feel like one or both of those women are demi-humans, but I can't remember what form they took. That might be useful for tag searches.

Comment: This did happen in the manga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [*Phantasm Trainer (Yuiitsu Muni no Saikyou Tamer)*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/5neupvy/yuiitsu-Muni-No-Saikyou-Tamer).

> It's difficult to be a phantasm tamer when no one believes in invisible followers, not to mention tamers already being quite unpopular.
>
> Follow our hero's journey to be recognized!
>
> [image]

Note that the phantasms he trains are in fact local spirits and that when he leaves the country, people's magic stops working.